# Density function. Finding coefficient

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

$f$ is a density function $f(x,y)=Cxy \mathbb{I}_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}(x,y)$.

Need to find C.

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f(u,v)du dv = 1$. How to use it here?

Comment: I believe your bounds are incorrect; otherwise, the integrals will diverge.

Answer (score 1):

$C\int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} xy dxdy=1$ so $C=4$. [ $\int_0^{1} xdx=\frac 1 2=\int_0^{1} ydy$].

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake. We can find a distribution function with my given connection. What if I will need to find distribution function? $\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} 4xy dx dy$ How it works?

Comment: @Atstovas Your integrals don't exist so you cannot find any $C$ in that case.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f(u,v)du dv = 1$ is not correct ! If $f$ is a density function, then

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,v)du dv = 1$.

From the definition of $f$ we get

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,v)du dv=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f(u,v)du dv$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake. We can find a distribution function with my given connection. What if I will need to find distribution function? $\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} 4xy dx dy$ How it works?